# Docker Toolbox Exit Status 1 Windows

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

Installed Docker Toolbox and the virtual box packaged with the toolbox (vbox 5.0.8) on Windows 8.

I get the following error when I start Docker quickstart

```
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
```

Thanks in advance. I have tried for a while and still stuck

Background to the problem:

1. I had virtualbox 4 and toolbox previously installed and they worked fine.
2. I uninstalled both.
3. I installed virtual box 5 on a non default path and got the above error so I uninstalled virtual box and toolbox.
4. I reinstalled toolbox and the virtual box that is part of the toolbox install.
5. I still get the same error.

I also get the following error when I start Kitematic:

```
D:\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D start default returned non zero exit code. Stderr: Docker Machine Version: 0.5.0 (04cfa58) Found binary path at .\docker-machine-driver-virtualbox.exe Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:51086 () Calling RpcServerDriver.GetVersion Using API Version 1 () Calling RpcServerDriver.SetConfigRaw () Calling RpcServerDriver.GetMachineName command=start machine=default (default) Calling RpcServerDriver.GetState (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo default --machinereadable (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | name="default" (default) DBG | groups="/" (default) DBG | ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)" (default) DBG | UUID="b06c8ade-3538-4a49-83b6-a3677a6850bb" (default) DBG | CfgFile="C:\\Users\\username\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\default.vbox" (default) DBG | SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\username\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Snapshots" (default) DBG | LogFldr="C:\\Users\\username\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Logs" (default) DBG | hardwareuuid="b06c8ade-3538-4a49-83b6-a3677a6850bb" (default) DBG | memory=1024 (default) DBG | pagefusion="off" (default) DBG | vram=8 (default) DBG | cpuexecutioncap=100 (default) DBG | hpet="on" (default) DBG | chipset="piix3" (default) DBG | firmware="BIOS" (default) DBG | cpus=1 (default) DBG | pae="on" (default) DBG | longmode="on" (default) DBG | cpuid-portability-level=0 (default) DBG | bootmenu="disabled" (default) DBG | boot1="dvd" (default) DBG | boot2="dvd" (default) DBG | boot3="disk" (default) DBG | boot4="none" (default) DBG | acpi="on" (default) DBG | ioapic="on" (default) DBG | biossystemtimeoffset=0 (default) DBG | rtcuseutc="on" (default) DBG | hwvirtex="on" (default) DBG | nestedpaging="on" (default) DBG | largepages="on" (default) DBG | vtxvpid="on" (default) DBG | vtxux="on" (default) DBG | paravirtprovider="default" (default) DBG | VMState="poweroff" (default) DBG | VMStateChangeTime="2015-11-20T23:41:31.367000000" (default) DBG | monitorcount=1 (default) DBG | accelerate3d="off" (default) DBG | accelerate2dvideo="off" (default) DBG | teleporterenabled="off" (default) DBG | teleporterport=0 (default) DBG | teleporteraddress="" (default) DBG | teleporterpassword="" (default) DBG | tracing-enabled="off" (default) DBG | tracing-allow-vm-access="off" (default) DBG | tracing-config="" (default) DBG | autostart-enabled="off" (default) DBG | autostart-delay=0 (default) DBG | defaultfrontend="" (default) DBG | storagecontrollername0="SATA" (default) DBG | storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci" (default) DBG | storagecontrollerinstance0="0" (default) DBG | storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30" (default) DBG | storagecontrollerportcount0="30" (default) DBG | storagecontrollerbootable0="on" (default) DBG | "SATA-0-0"="C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso" (default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-0-0"="62373112-2aa1-48dd-852d-52425f47b5fb" (default) DBG | "SATA-tempeject"="off" (default) DBG | "SATA-IsEjected"="off" (default) DBG | "SATA-1-0"="C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk" (default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-1-0"="73a42406-5257-477d-b40b-36014e47cc89" (default) DBG | "SATA-2-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-3-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-4-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-5-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-6-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-7-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-8-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-9-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-10-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-11-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-12-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-13-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-14-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-15-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-16-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-17-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-18-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-19-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-20-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-21-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-22-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-23-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-24-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-25-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-26-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-27-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-28-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-29-0"="none" (default) DBG | natnet1="nat" (default) DBG | macaddress1="080027E130C4" (default) DBG | cableconnected1="on" (default) DBG | nic1="nat" (default) DBG | nictype1="82540EM" (default) DBG | nicspeed1="0" (default) DBG | mtu="0" (default) DBG | sockSnd="64" (default) DBG | sockRcv="64" (default) DBG | tcpWndSnd="64" (default) DBG | tcpWndRcv="64" (default) DBG | Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,50800,,22" (default) DBG | hostonlyadapter2="VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3" (default) DBG | macaddress2="0800270AE2D6" (default) DBG | cableconnected2="on" (default) DBG | nic2="hostonly" (default) DBG | nictype2="82540EM" (default) DBG | nicspeed2="0" (default) DBG | nic3="none" (default) DBG | nic4="none" (default) DBG | nic5="none" (default) DBG | nic6="none" (default) DBG | nic7="none" (default) DBG | nic8="none" (default) DBG | hidpointing="ps2mouse" (default) DBG | hidkeyboard="ps2kbd" (default) DBG | uart1="off" (default) DBG | uart2="off" (default) DBG | lpt1="off" (default) DBG | lpt2="off" (default) DBG | audio="none" (default) DBG | clipboard="disabled" (default) DBG | draganddrop="disabled" (default) DBG | vrde="off" (default) DBG | usb="off" (default) DBG | ehci="off" (default) DBG | xhci="off" (default) DBG | SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="c/Users" (default) DBG | SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="c:\Users" (default) DBG | vcpenabled="off" (default) DBG | vcpscreens=0 (default) DBG | vcpfile="C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.webm" (default) DBG | vcpwidth=1024 (default) DBG | vcpheight=768 (default) DBG | vcprate=512 (default) DBG | vcpfps=25 (default) DBG | GuestMemoryBalloon=0 (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) Calling RpcServerDriver.Start (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo default --machinereadable (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | name="default" (default) DBG | groups="/" (default) DBG | ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)" (default) DBG | UUID="b06c8ade-3538-4a49-83b6-a3677a6850bb" (default) DBG | CfgFile="C:\\Users\\username\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\default.vbox" (default) DBG | SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\username\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Snapshots" (default) DBG | LogFldr="C:\\Users\\username\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Logs" (default) DBG | hardwareuuid="b06c8ade-3538-4a49-83b6-a3677a6850bb" (default) DBG | memory=1024 (default) DBG | pagefusion="off" (default) DBG | vram=8 (default) DBG | cpuexecutioncap=100 (default) DBG | hpet="on" (default) DBG | chipset="piix3" (default) DBG | firmware="BIOS" (default) DBG | cpus=1 (default) DBG | pae="on" (default) DBG | longmode="on" (default) DBG | cpuid-portability-level=0 (default) DBG | bootmenu="disabled" (default) DBG | boot1="dvd" (default) DBG | boot2="dvd" (default) DBG | boot3="disk" (default) DBG | boot4="none" (default) DBG | acpi="on" (default) DBG | ioapic="on" (default) DBG | biossystemtimeoffset=0 (default) DBG | rtcuseutc="on" (default) DBG | hwvirtex="on" (default) DBG | nestedpaging="on" (default) DBG | largepages="on" (default) DBG | vtxvpid="on" (default) DBG | vtxux="on" (default) DBG | paravirtprovider="default" (default) DBG | VMState="poweroff" (default) DBG | VMStateChangeTime="2015-11-20T23:41:31.367000000" (default) DBG | monitorcount=1 (default) DBG | accelerate3d="off" (default) DBG | accelerate2dvideo="off" (default) DBG | teleporterenabled="off" (default) DBG | teleporterport=0 (default) DBG | teleporteraddress="" (default) DBG | teleporterpassword="" (default) DBG | tracing-enabled="off" (default) DBG | tracing-allow-vm-access="off" (default) DBG | tracing-config="" (default) DBG | autostart-enabled="off" (default) DBG | autostart-delay=0 (default) DBG | defaultfrontend="" (default) DBG | storagecontrollername0="SATA" (default) DBG | storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci" (default) DBG | storagecontrollerinstance0="0" (default) DBG | storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30" (default) DBG | storagecontrollerportcount0="30" (default) DBG | storagecontrollerbootable0="on" (default) DBG | "SATA-0-0"="C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso" (default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-0-0"="62373112-2aa1-48dd-852d-52425f47b5fb" (default) DBG | "SATA-tempeject"="off" (default) DBG | "SATA-IsEjected"="off" (default) DBG | "SATA-1-0"="C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk" (default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-1-0"="73a42406-5257-477d-b40b-36014e47cc89" (default) DBG | "SATA-2-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-3-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-4-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-5-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-6-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-7-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-8-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-9-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-10-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-11-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-12-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-13-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-14-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-15-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-16-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-17-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-18-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-19-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-20-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-21-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-22-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-23-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-24-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-25-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-26-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-27-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-28-0"="none" (default) DBG | "SATA-29-0"="none" (default) DBG | natnet1="nat" (default) DBG | macaddress1="080027E130C4" (default) DBG | cableconnected1="on" (default) DBG | nic1="nat" (default) DBG | nictype1="82540EM" (default) DBG | nicspeed1="0" (default) DBG | mtu="0" (default) DBG | sockSnd="64" (default) DBG | sockRcv="64" (default) DBG | tcpWndSnd="64" (default) DBG | tcpWndRcv="64" (default) DBG | Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,50800,,22" (default) DBG | hostonlyadapter2="VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3" (default) DBG | macaddress2="0800270AE2D6" (default) DBG | cableconnected2="on" (default) DBG | nic2="hostonly" (default) DBG | nictype2="82540EM" (default) DBG | nicspeed2="0" (default) DBG | nic3="none" (default) DBG | nic4="none" (default) DBG | nic5="none" (default) DBG | nic6="none" (default) DBG | nic7="none" (default) DBG | nic8="none" (default) DBG | hidpointing="ps2mouse" (default) DBG | hidkeyboard="ps2kbd" (default) DBG | uart1="off" (default) DBG | uart2="off" (default) DBG | lpt1="off" (default) DBG | lpt2="off" (default) DBG | audio="none" (default) DBG | clipboard="disabled" (default) DBG | draganddrop="disabled" (default) DBG | vrde="off" (default) DBG | usb="off" (default) DBG | ehci="off" (default) DBG | xhci="off" (default) DBG | SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="c/Users" (default) DBG | SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="c:\Users" (default) DBG | vcpenabled="off" (default) DBG | vcpscreens=0 (default) DBG | vcpfile="C:\Users\username\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.webm" (default) DBG | vcpwidth=1024 (default) DBG | vcpheight=768 (default) DBG | vcprate=512 (default) DBG | vcpfps=25 (default) DBG | GuestMemoryBalloon=0 (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | using 192.168.99.6 for dhcp address (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter (default) DBG | GUID: 819b42c6-05d5-427d-8db8-562f3f1a0db9 (default) DBG | DHCP: Disabled (default) DBG | IPAddress: 192.168.56.1 (default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.255.0 (default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:a1a5:80d0:d5a7:2a7b (default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64 (default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00 (default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet (default) DBG | Status: Up (default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter (default) DBG | (default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 (default) DBG | GUID: b219f9bf-0606-4015-9045-e63c7d05828c (default) DBG | DHCP: Disabled (default) DBG | IPAddress: 192.168.99.1 (default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.255.0 (default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:a1fa:344c:b6d8:fd9e (default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64 (default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00 (default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet (default) DBG | Status: Up (default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 (default) DBG | (default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3 (default) DBG | GUID: 51fdc633-f478-41f2-8c4d-0d54315d43fa (default) DBG | DHCP: Disabled (default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.44.129 (default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0 (default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:4cfd:eac1:5127:2c81 (default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64 (default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00 (default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet (default) DBG | Status: Up (default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3 (default) DBG | (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --nicpromisc2 deny --hostonlyadapter2 VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 --cableconnected2 on (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --natpf1 delete ssh (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --natpf1 ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,51088,,22 (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless (default) DBG | STDOUT: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | Waiting for VM "default" to power on... (default) DBG | VM "default" has been successfully started. (default) DBG | } (default) DBG | STDERR: (default) DBG | { (default) DBG | } exit status 1
```

EDIT 26112015
Following steps resolved my issue

1. uninstall Virtual Box 5.0.8 and replacing with Virtual Box 4.3 from
   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds.
2. Run virtual box repair tool to resolve a bug which prevented me from adding Ethernet adapters (repair tool can be accessed by re running the vbox install exe when virtual box is already installed)
3. Added an Ethernet adapter to virtual box (Make sure the Virtual Machine is powered off. VirtualBox will not allow you to modify the network adapters while the VM is running)
4. started docker which powered up the virtual box fine and used the ethernet adapter.

I also carried out the following steps but am not sure if this contributed to the resolution.

1. Uninstalled both docker-toolbox and virtualbox
2. I deleted .virtualbox and .docker virtual machines folder from my
   user profile before reinstalling
3. Removed references to virtualbox from registry (avoid this step if
   possible but if nothing else has worked then make sure you backup
       registry before attempting. I follwed details on this link
       http://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/
       )
4. Installed VBox 4.3 and then installed docker toolbox (i did not
   install the virtual box as part of the docker install)

Comment: You need to delete to your docker-machine VM files too after uninstall

Comment: Tried that already, I deleted my .virtualbox folder which contains my virtual machines. Docker then created a new default machine but same problem

Comment: I have the same question . Did you solve this ?

Comment: i have edited my question with steps that resolved the issue for me

Comment: I had the same error, and a series of uninstalls and installs worked to fix it for me with the latest VirtualBox, GitWindows, and Docker-machine on windows 8 box. I think the thing that did the trick was deleting the Virtualbox 'default' box, because I had modified that , and Docker-machine is relying on it for the initial tests.